# Stacking columns in a particular order (bootstrap 3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap. Overall the official manual is easy to understand but I'm trying to stack columns in a certain way between desktop and mobile view and can't figure it out. Image shows what I'm attempting to achieve.

What I'm trying to do

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="column1" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">column1</div>
        <div id="column2" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">column2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="Desc1&2" class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">desc1&2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="column3" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">column3</div>
        <div id="column4" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">column4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="Desc3&4" class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">DESC3&4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! In your example columns 1 through 4 get stacked on top of each other and description columns get stacked at the bottom. The result i'm after is a stack of: col 1, col 2, desc1&2, col 3, col 4, desc3&4

Comment: still same result :)

Comment: Updated so sorry didn't see well your structure. hope this time you find what you need :)

Comment: thank you, and it makes total sense now that I look at what you did.